# Nonlinear least squares estimator with unknown variance

Tags: nonlinear-system, least-squares, maximum-likelihood

I have a standard NLS problem as follows:

$\ y=f(x)+v, v\sim \mathcal N (0,\sigma^2\Sigma)$

Here, $\Sigma$ is SPD, and $\sigma$ is unknown. If we knew the variance, I think the solution is pretty straight-forward (I may be wrong about this too). Namely, we just compute the log likelihood of our normally distributed function v, and since $\ v=y-f(x)$,  we can plug it in to get the objective is to minimize $\ (y-f(x))^T \Sigma^{-1} (y-f(x))$

but I get confused when the $\sigma$ comes into play. I know that this is a maximum likelihood estimation problem, but I am not sure how to take what derivative to get a MLE estimate for $\sigma$ in this case.

Any pointers would be very helpful. Thanks!

Comment: Your notation is unclear. Do you mean $$v\sim\mathcal N(0,\sigma^2\Sigma)$$ ?

Comment: I'm sorry, but your question does not make much sense. (1) How do you estimate $f$ without assuming any structure? I.e., what exactly you are estimating? (2) If you don't put any restrictions on $\Sigma$, then what does it matter if you know that the co-variance can be expressed as $\sigma^2 \Sigma$? What $\sigma^2$ stands for in this case?

Comment: @polfosol: Yes, I corrected it.Thanks

Comment: @V.V: We know form of $\ f(x)$ so it is not to be estimated, it is a known nonlinear function. We don't know noise vector v and variance parameter $\sigma$. $\sigma$ is basically multiplied with each diagonal entry of covariance matrix $\Sigma$. Also, $\Sigma$ is known too and it's nonsingular. So this problem is a (supposedly) simple MLE problem. We get MLE estimates for $\ x$ and $\sigma$ by taking some derivatives.

Comment: I see. Is $\Sigma$ diagonal?

Comment: @V.V: Yes, and as nonsingular implies, all diagonal entries are nonzero.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the comments - i.e., the fact that $\Sigma$ is diagonal such that $\Sigma = diag(w_1,...,w_n)$, denote $\sigma^2 = \theta$,
$$
\mathcal{L}(\theta ; y_1,...,y_n) =  (2 \pi)^{-k/2}|\Sigma|^{-1/2}\exp\{ - \frac{1}{2}(y-\mu)'\Sigma^{-1} ( y- \mu) \}\, 
$$
or 
$$
\mathcal{L}(\theta ; y_1,...,y_n) =  (2 \pi)^{-n/2}(\theta^n\prod w_i)^{-1/2}\exp\{ - \frac{1}{2\theta}\sum_{i=1}^n\frac{1}{w_i}(y_i -\mu)^2 \}.  
$$
Hence, 
$$
\mathcal{l}(\theta ; y_1,...,y_n) \propto   - \frac{n}{2}\ln\theta- \frac{1}{2\theta}\sum_{i=1}^n \frac{1}{w_i} (y_i - \mu)^2 ,  
$$
by differentiating it w.r.t $\theta$ and reaarenging the equations you get 
$$
\hat{\sigma}^2=\hat{\theta} = \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n\frac{1}{w_i} (y_i - \mu)^2\,.
$$
You can easily verify that it indeed the Maximum LE of $\sigma^2$, and if you don't know $f(x)$, then just plug in $\hat{f}(x)$ instead of $\mu$. In addition, note that this is exactly a WLS problem.